# Jquery menu a:link change color when clicked

Tags: jquery

i am trying to make some code that makes me able to click a link on my navigation line and then it will change color, when i click another link the color will change back and the new link will get the color instead! However something seems to be wrong with my code ;( Can anyone help me? :)

This is in my try_1.php file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="try_1.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/click.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
        <div id="mainNavMenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Hjem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CV</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Foto album</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pr&aelig;diker</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Artikler</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Foredrag</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Kalender</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is in my try_1.css file:

```
a:link,a:visited{
    color:green;
    font-family:calibri;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#mainNavMenu ul li {
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
}
#mainNavMenu ul li a:link{
    color:blue;
    font-size:18px;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-left:20px;
    line-height:60px;'
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    background:gray;
}
#mainNavMenu ul li a:hover{
    color:yellow;
}

#mainNavMenu .changeColor{
    background-color:white;
}
```

This is in my click.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                var targetElement = $("#mainNavMenu li");

                targetElement.click(function() {
                    $(this).addClass("changeColor");
                });

            });
```

And of course I also have a jquery.js file but not gonna copy/paste that code :)

Hope u guys can help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `.siblings()` will be useful in your case.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var targetElement = $("#mainNavMenu li");           
    targetElement.click(function() {
       $(this).siblings().removeClass("changeColor");
       $(this).addClass("changeColor");
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, He said I am not gonna copy & paste code :D +1 for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are applying a `background: gray` style to your `<a/>` hyperlinks in the `#mainNavMenu ul li a:link` rule. But, you are applying the `changeColor` classname to the parent `<li/>` elements.

The `background` style applied to `<li/>` will be overwritten by the `background` style in the child `<a/>` always ending up in `gray`.

You need to apply your rule to the hyperlinks instead. The following rule is a bit too wordy but I think it get the idea through.

Use

```
#mainNavMenu ul li a:link.changeColor {
  background-color:white;
}
```

instead of

```
#mainNavMenu .changeColor{
    background-color:white;
}
```

And update your current selector in your code.

```
$(function(){
    var $targetElement = $("#mainNavMenu li a");           
    $targetElement.click(function() {
       $targetElement.removeClass("changeColor");
       $(this).addClass("changeColor");
    });
});
```

[**See a live example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/TRGCK/)

Answer (score 0):

this should do it..

```
#mainNavMenu ul li.changeColor{
background-color:white;
```

}

since your are adding the class to `<li>` here... `$(this)` in your jquery refers to `<li>`..

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var targetElement = $("#mainNavMenu li");
    targetElement.click(function() {
        targetElement.removeClass('changeColor');
        $(this).addClass("changeColor");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('.menu a').click(function () {.  
            jQuery('.menu a').removeClass('select');
            jQuery(this).addClass('select');

        });
    });

</script>
<nav class="menu">
    <a href="#" class="select">all</a>
    <a href="#" ">shoes</a>
    <a href="#" ">dress</a>
    <a href="#" ">hat</a>
    <a href="#" ">trousers</a>
    <a href="#" ">shirt</a>

</nav>
```

REMEMBER:setting properties in CSS include:
::selection
{
color:#fff;
background:#ed1e79;
text-shadow:none;
}
::-moz-selection    //this properties need for MOZILA FIREFOX
{
color:#fff;
background:#ed1e79;
text-shadow:none;
}

i think that a method very easy working and you can easy understanding
Notes: when you instruct someone let is guide easily and most concise